# How to split up integers

Tags: c++, integer

in the program that I am working on I have 9 digit integers from the following range: 111111111 - 999999999.

I have three cases that I need to look at. In one, I need to set an integer equal to the last 3 digits of the number, next I have to set the `int` = the middle 3 digits, and then I have to set the `int` = the first 3 digits.

How would I do something like that? I don't know how to work with this without spaces between digits or anything like that.

Comment: You want us to do your work for you?  Or you already have an outline or some basic code to show us?

Comment: You can use the modulo operator and division by 10 to grab individual digits, but if you are going to be working a lot with these kinds of operations I suggest creating a custom Integer class which contains each 3-digit part individually and can reconstruct it easily, e.g. by `123456789 = 123 * 10^6 + 456 * 10^3 + 789`. At least it makes more sense that way to me.

Comment: While you've mentioned "space", that means it can be a string. So, do you know there's way to get a sub-string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show your attempted work, but this one is fairly simple using division and modulo (the remainder of a division - so `1234 % 100` would be `34`):

```
int num = 123456789;
int last = num%1000;// last = 789
int tmp = num/1000; // tmp = 123456
int mid = tmp%1000; // mid = 456
int first = tmp/1000; // first = 123
```

Answer (score 0):

If your numbers are strings, then you should look into the `std::string` manipulators. In particular `substr` should suit your needs.

If your number is an `int` then I would suggest looking at the modulo operator (`%`).